# Azure DocumentDB client calls result in an error from Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Continuous Azure Webjob that checks DocumentDb on each message from QueueTrigger. Use DocumentDB SDK 1.10 for .NET. I keep getting errors like this from time to time:

*Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted :443
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.GatewayServiceConfigurationReader.d__0.MoveNext()*

I have dependency injection (StructureMap) through the JobActivator and use non-static method to process queue triggers within Functions class. use

DocumentClient is wrapped in a static class so it should be one instance per WebJob.

Also some web apps (ASP.NET MVC) use their own document db connection with same connection string from time to time. I could not find any information about this issue. What could be go wrong here?

Changed internal  code:

```
class Program
{
    public static IReliableReadWriteDocumentClient Client { get; set; }
    static void Main()
    {
        Client = // initialize client with settings from app config
    }
}

public class Functions
{
    public async Task ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("myqueuename")] CustomerRequest customerRequest,
            TextWriter dashboardLogger)
    {
        // usage from some place which runs on QueueTrigger

        var customerRepository = new DocumentDbRepository<Customer>(Program.Client, databaseId,
                    () => "Customers");
       // additional logic
    }
}
```

Repository class is taken from here: https://github.com/Crokus/documentdb-repo

Comment: Can you share the static class wrapping the DocumentClient? It appears that you are creating multiple instances of it. Also, is your WebJob running via an Azure Web Site?

Comment: Please make sure whether you call DocumentClient IDisposable.Dispose implementation when you finish using it. Besides, please try to [run your continuous WebJob as a Singleton](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2014/05/19/how-to-run-a-continuous-webjob-as-a-singleton/) and check whether same issue will appear.

Comment: The job is running through the Azure website in Singleton mode. Now I didn't call Dispose manually but I've tried that yearlier and was getting the same issue. Before that I was creating DocumentClient for each db call on Repository layer in using blocks. I'll share the code later today. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Which version of .NET SDK are you using? How is your Webjob calling these APIs? Calling CreateNew and GetItemsById in that order? I'm not sure whether the documentClient variable inside the lambda expression is locally scopped or refers to the private static variable that you defined above. You may be creating a new instance with every call. You should be able to use a c# property here and check for the existence inside the get method and return the private variable is already initialized, if not create a new one.

Comment: Couple more things: Can you tell the VM size you are using on Azure Websites? We have seen instances where web jobs didn't had enough budget to complete SSL handshake. Also, do you see high CPU during that time? Can you add debug trace inside the CreateNew method to ensure that you are not indeed calling it multiple times which is most likely the cause? Can you capture the top-level DocumentException that gets thrown and send us the ActivityId/ErrorCode/ErrorMessage?

Comment: Can you capture the ETLs for us during this process? The instructions are at https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/master/docs/documentdb-sdk_capture_etl.md. This works only in 1.11.0 version of the SDK and above, so please ensure that you have the latest SDK.

Comment: I use 1.10 SDK. Updated the source code. VM on Azure uses B1 tier (Basic: 1 Small).

Comment: Stacktrace: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/PShchegolevatykh/5c7696ebecf669d05b973fab79d3d5b7/raw/f20f62596e1be3945cc90c80370e8f3663bfc661/gistfile1.txt

Comment: Pavel, can you email us on askdocdb at Microsoft dot com as we might need more details from you? Also, I asked several things in my comments above, so if you can provide all those in the email it would help us speed up the investigation.